# Is there any relationship between $\log \det(AB+I)$ and $\mbox{trace}(B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say $\mathbf{A}$ is a diagonal matrix and $\mathbf{B}$ is a symmetric, positive definite matrices and $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$

In fact, I try to maximize the term logdet$\left(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{I_{n}}\right)$ and find the relationship between logdet$\left(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{I_{n}}\right)$ and trace$\left(\mathbf{B}\right)$, where $\mathbf{I_{n}}$ is an identity matrix. I think we can start with eigenvalues but I got stopped. Can someone help me keep going ahead. Thank you!

Below is my process: (maybe it is useless)

set $\lambda_{\mathbf{A}}$ are eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ and $\lambda_{A_1} \ge \lambda_{A_2} \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_{A_n}$. Similarly, we set $\lambda_{\mathbf{B}}$ are eigenvalues of $\mathbf{B}$ and $\lambda_{B_1} \ge \lambda_{B_2} \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_{B_n}$. Now  logdet$\left(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{I_{n}}\right)$ is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^n log \left( 1+\lambda_{A_i}\lambda_{B_i} \right)$ and trace$\left(\mathbf{B}\right)$ is equivalent to $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_{B_i}$ but I can not go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are maximizing $ \log \det (AB + I) $, then you are probably interested in its derivative. Determinant, trace and derivative are connected by the formula
$$
 \dfrac{d}{dt} \det (C(t)) = \det (C(t)) \operatorname{trace}(C(t)^{-1} C'(t))
$$
(see https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/01/13/matrix-identities-as-derivatives-of-determinant-identities/ )

Now write $C = AB + I$, and we get
\begin{align}
 \partial_t \log \det (AB + I) &= \frac{\det (AB + I) \operatorname{trace}((AB+I)^{-1} \partial_t (AB + I))} {\det (AB + I)} \\
&= \operatorname{trace}((AB+I)^{-1} \partial_t (AB + I)).
\end{align}
To compute the last derivative, I should know with respect to what you are maximizing the log-det-thing.

Comment: I think matrix $\mathbf{B}$ does not depend on a real parameter t. In my case, the matrix $\mathbf{B}$ can be in the form of $\left( \mathbf{A^T}\mathbf{A}\right)^{-1}$ and is dependent on the matrix $\mathbf{A}$ where $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ . Does this help you?

Comment: I used $t$ as a "placeholder", you can replace it with e.g. $A(i,j)$ (the $i,j$th element of the matrix $A$), if you are maximizing so that $A(i,j)$ is one of optimization parameters.

So, it seems that your problem is of form
$$
 \min_{\textrm{over what?}} \log \det (A (A^T A)^{-1} + I).
$$
If $A$ is indeed a diagonal matrix, then this simplifies very much.

I don't know the full problem, but it looks like some D-optimality related thing, where $AB + I$ is the "information matrix", and maximing its determinant gives the most informative matrix, in some sense.

Comment: I am sorry that I make a name mistake in my last comment. Actually, matrix $\mathbf{B}$ is in the form of $\left(\mathbf{X^TX}\right)^{-1}$ and is independent of matrix $\mathbf{A}$. It seems that D-optimality is related and I will study it. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Could I ask one question about derivative($\partial_{\mathit{t}}$)? Supposed I got the derivative of $\mathtt{logdet X}$ function, which is in the form of $\mathtt{t}\bullet \mathbf{C}$. Here $\mathit{t}\gt 0$ and matrix $\mathbf{C}$ is a constant PSD matrix. So $\mathtt{t}\bullet \mathbf{C}\gt0$. And we know that $\mathtt{logdet X}$ function is a $\mathit{concave}$ function and local maximum value appear at zero derivative value. So can I make a conclusion that to $\mathbf{maximize}$ the  $\mathtt{logdet X}$ function, we need to $\mathbf{minimize}$ the value of $\mathit{t}$?

Comment: Are you planning to find the global maximum analytically, or iterating numerically to maximize the function? In the first case, with a concave function, the maximum is at the point where the gradient (i.e., all partial derivatives) are zero. In the second case, computing the gradient is naturally useful (as the gradient vector tells in which direction the function grows fastest).

Knowing more of the original problem could be helpful, as I cannot know what is the aim.

Comment: Very thankful! Your answer is very clear. In fact, I am using a least-squares estimator and trying to find the relationship that maximizing mutual information(MI) is equivalent to minimizing the mean squares error(MSE).

Comment: And I read a paper (ref: [link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/329311609_Remote_Compressive_Sensing_for_Noisy_M2M_Networks)) and in Page.3 the upper right corner the author says " Since (14) is a concave function, .... Therefore, maximizing the MI is equivalent to minimizing the MSE.". I have some confusion about this because as I know the maximum is at the point where the gradient (i.e., all partial derivatives) are zero (same as your last comment). Is there any concept I miss about this ?

Comment: I looked quickly at the article. In my knowledge, minimizing the trace (= MSE) is called A-optimality, whereas maximizing the log det (= MI) is called D-optimality, and these two do not lead to the same design, in general. I should see some book that discusses these information matrices and optimal experiment design (A-, D-, whatever optimality) and compute the traces and determinants myself, before I say something completely wrong...

Comment: Really really thankful! I am trying to figure it out. If I have any progress, I will make comment here.